# Is it possible to define a function in the table property of Model Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Colleagues, help out. I have a list_books_hist(?) function in my database (the database is built on a separate scheme, not tied to migrations) (which we will go to the id and it returns a line from the table of outdated books)

```
class BooksListHist extends Model
{
  protected $connection = 'db_main';
  protected $table = 'lst_books_hist(?)'; //--> can I do like this?
}
```

Then how do I build a query by passing an ID card there? Using AddBinding? How can I work with the BooksListHist model in this case ?
`BooksListHist::addBinding("id_book", "select")->select()` ? But in this case it doesn't work

Comment: I think even if that worked, it wouldn't make sense as how would you get the id, before the object is fetched from the database?

Comment: @mrhn This row Query Work

Comment: @mrhn

$builder = $connection->TABLE(
DB::raw("lst_books_hist(?) as lb")
)
->SELECT("lb.*")
->addBinding($IdFilter["value"], "from");